# Pie Chart Slice Sizing in ArcGIS-Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, chart

I have two fields I would like to show in pie charts on a map.

I'm having trouble understanding how field 2 is represented as a part of field 1. If a polygon in field 2 is over half of field 1, why is it being shown as almost 1/4 of the pie chart? - confused!

For example - this pie chart is showing the light blue field as 80,000 and the dark blue field as 70,000

[image]

I read in the help files that it converts your data to map units, so it is showing field 2 based on its proportion of the size it has set as the scale. I think.

But anyway, it is misrepresenting my data...I need to show field 2 as half the pie chart if the figure is half of field 1. How to get around this? I've tried setting is as a ratio but it still doesn't look right.

nm I think I get it after reading excel help. What I need to  do is convert fields 1 and 2 to a proportion of 100, so 80,000 would become 5 and 60,000 would become 4. Easy way to do this using field calculator?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, to help you get an answer, it is generally best to give an example of what you you are trying to achieve. For example, you could give a subset of your data and and example of how you want the Pie Chart to look. This not only helps you get an answer but helps future users who may view your question ..

Comment: Are fields a and b meant to be fields 1 and 2?  In any event I think the default is that a 50:50 split shows as two equal halves i.e. values are both half the 100 in total. A 50:100 split would show as 33% and 67% i.e. a third and two-thirds of the 150 in total.

Comment: yes I think I get what your saying, it is splitting the data 50:50 so the second field is shown as a proportion of half the pie, right? but I think it is not really representing my data well. The user would find that confusing

Comment: You showed an example of how ArcMap displays the chart (field 1: 80,000; field 2: 70,000). Please add a second image how you want the Pie Chart to look.